# Thermal Printer drivers on Raspbian

Tags: drivers, raspberry-pi, printer

I have recently bought a thermal printer (NPI NP-KV30DK), and I was trying to make it work under linux (Raspbian to be exact). I have already installed cups but I have no idea how to make the printer work with it. I also downloaded the right driver for my Raspberry Pi on the [manufacturer website](https://www.primex.co.jp/npiweb/index_e.jsp) but I don't know how to install it either since it's a .so file.

I'm inexperienced so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I can't work out what I am meant to find by following the link.